# how to avoid the system bar in android ,flutter?

Tags: flutter, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to add bottom app bar but there is a problem, the android system app bar keep hiding my app bar. What I want to achieve is my bottom app bar to expand the bottom as the same height as the bottom system bar

```
 bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
        child: BottomAppBar(
          color: Color(0xFFDFFFE6),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text("Trạng thái"),
            icon: Icon(
            Icons.assignment_turned_in,
            color: primary,
          ),),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title : Text("Đổi quà"),
              icon: Icon(
              Icons.redeem,
              color: primary,
            ),)
        ],
        ),),
      ),
```

My android's style file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

    </style>

    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item><!-- Normal Background-->
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` should do what you want.

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values)` to show it again.

Don't forget to import it.

`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: Where should I put this code? In the initstate method or the beginning of the method build

Comment: The problem if I use this code is my top app bar doesn't scale maximum anymore

Comment: i tend to put it in the `initState(){ /* ... */}` of my class.

Try adding `sized: false` for the height fix: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24472#issuecomment-440015464